# Differentiate an integral of function(that has 2 variables: u, t) with respect to one of the variables(dt)

Tags: integration, derivatives

I was working through some proofs and they differentiated an integral of function(that has 2 variables: u, t) with respect to one of the variables(dt). I would like to know where I can find information on how to do this.

In my attempt to figure this out I made up some random assumption(that 'felt' correct) with no idea if it works for all, but seems to work for the examples I made up.

Example Let $X = t\sin(u)$, thus

\begin{equation}
I = \int^u_{t_1}t\sin(u)dt
\end{equation}
then
\begin{equation}
\frac{d I }{du} = u\sin(u) + \frac{1}{2}u^2\cos(u) - \frac{1}{2}{t_1}^2\cos(u)
\end{equation}

Question is : Can we represent any function (like the one above) like this:

\begin{equation}
\frac{d I }{du} = X|_{t=u} + \int^u_{t_1}\frac{\partial}{\partial u}Xdt
\end{equation}

I made up some indices gymnastics to help: rasing indix for integration, lowering for differentiation.

$\int ^u_{t_1}X_{ut}dt$ >>> integrate w.r.t $t$ >>> $X_u^t|^u_{t_1}$ >>> use end points of integral >>> $X_u^u - X_u^{t_1}$

then the next step is to differentiate w.r.t $u$ and so:

$\frac{d}{du}X_u^u$ >>>"differentiate using my "product rule" ">>> $X_{uu} + X_\bar{u}^u$.

Then for $X_u^{t_1}$ >>> differentiate w.r.t $u$ >>>$X_\bar{u}^{t_1}$

Thus inconclusion for differentiate we get: $\frac{d}{du}(\int ^u_{t_1}X_{ut}dt) = X_{uu} + X_\bar{u}^u -X_\bar{u}^{t_1}$

key: $X_{uu}$ means "leave function $X$ unchange and sub in $u$ for $t$"

$X_\bar{u}^u$ means "first differentiate function $X$ w.r.t $u$ and then integrate w.r.t $t$ sub in $u$ for $t$"

$X_\bar{u}^{t_1}$ means "first differentiate function $X$ w.r.t $u$ and then integrate w.r.t $t$ sub in $t_1$ for $t$"

so for the example:

The answer we should get is:
\begin{equation}
I = \int^u_{t_1}t\sin(u)dt = \frac{1}{2}t^2\sin(u)|^u_{t_1} = \frac{1}{2}u^2\sin(u) - \frac{1}{2}{t_1}^2\sin(u)
\end{equation}
now finally differentiate w.r.t $u$:
\begin{equation}
\frac{dI}{du} = \frac{d}{du}(\frac{1}{2}u^2\sin(u) - \frac{1}{2}{t_1}^2\sin(u)) = u\sin(u) + \frac{1}{2}u^2\cos(u) - \frac{1}{2}{t_1}^2\cos(u)
\end{equation}

Now we try to get this answer using my method:

$X_{uu} = t\sin(u)|_{t=u} = u\sin(u)$

then for $X_u^u$:

$\frac{d}{du}X = \frac{d}{du}t\sin(u) = t\cos(u)$

integrate w.r.t $t$ and then let t =u,

$\int t\cos(u) = \frac{1}{2}t^2\cos(u)|_{t=u} = \frac{1}{2}u^2\cos(u)$

then for $X_\bar{u}^{t_1}$:

$\frac{d}{du}X = \frac{d}{du}t\sin(u) = t\cos(u)$

integrate w.r.t $t$ and then let t =t_1,

$\int t\cos(u) = \frac{1}{2}t^2\cos(u)|_{t=t_1} = \frac{1}{2}{t_1}^2\cos(u)$

Finally subbing these in $X_{uu} + X_\bar{u}^u -X_\bar{u}^{t_1}$ we get:
$u\sin(u) + \frac{1}{2}u^2\cos(u) - \frac{1}{2}{t_1}^2\cos(u)$

which is what we wanted to get.

Answer (score 1):

To me I would like to write $X$ as $X(u,t)$. Then the integral could be written as $\int_{t_1}^{u}X(u,t)\mathrm{d}t$. To do differentiation with respect to variable $u$ on both sides, one can show
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}I}{\mathrm{d}u}=X(u,u)+\int_{t_1}^{u}\frac{\partial X(u,t)}{\partial u}\mathrm{d}t=u\sin(u)+\int_{t_1}^{u}t\cos(u)\mathrm{d}t$$
which is the same result you got.
The more generalized formula when $I=\int_{f(u,t)}^{g(u,t)}X(u,t)\mathrm{d}t$ is
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}I}{\mathrm{d}u}=\int_{f(u,t)}^{g(u,t)}\frac{\partial X(u,t)}{\partial u}\mathrm{d}t+\frac{\partial g(u,t)}{\partial u}\cdot X(u,g(u,t))-\frac{\partial f(u,t)}{\partial u}\cdot X(u,f(u,t))$$
To prove it we can begin from an easier case $I(u)=\int_{f(u)}^{g(u)}X(u,t)\mathrm{d}t$ where $f,g$ are both differentiable and $\frac{\partial X(u,t)}{\partial u}$ is continuous.

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\lim_{h\to0}\frac{I(u+h)-I(u)}{h} &= \lim_{h\to0}\frac{\int_{f(u+h)}^{g(u+h)}X(u+h,t)\mathrm{d}t-\int_{f(u)}^{g(u)}X(u,t)\mathrm{d}t}{h} \\
&= \lim_{h\to0}\frac{\int_{f(u+h)}^{g(u+h)}X(u+h,t)\mathrm{d}t-\int_{f(u+h)}^{g(u+h)}X(u,t)\mathrm{d}t+\int_{f(u+h)}^{g(u+h)}X(u,t)\mathrm{d}t-\int_{f(u)}^{g(u)}X(u,t)\mathrm{d}t}{h} \\
&= \lim_{h\to0}\frac{\int_{f(u+h)}^{g(u+h)}(X(u+h,t)-X(u,t))\mathrm{d}t+\int_{g(u)}^{g(u+h)}X(u,t)\mathrm{d}t-\int_{f(u)}^{f(u+h)}X(u,t)\mathrm{d}t}{h}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
In the first integral it is $$\frac{1}{h}\int_{f(u+h)}^{g(u+h)}(X(u+h,t)-X(u,t))\mathrm{d}t=\int_{f(u+h)}^{g(u+h)}\frac{\partial X(u+\theta_1 h,t)}{\partial u}\mathrm{d}t\to\int_{f(u)}^{g(u)}\frac{\partial X(u,t)}{\partial u}\mathrm{d}t$$ where $0<\theta_1<1$.

In the second, $$\frac{1}{h}\int_{g(u)}^{g(u+h)}X(u,t)\mathrm{d}t\to g'(u)\cdot X(u,g(u))$$
while the third one is similar.